# Disable spring security https redirecting

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, https

I am working on a web application and configured ssl certificate to run on https in Tomcat.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" keystoreFile="conf/expchannel.pfx" keystorePass="***" keystoreType="PKCS12">
```

For some reasons, client wants to run it on 8080 port. Should not matter.

The problem is with Spring security login interceptor. Once it gets the request, it automatically redirects to login page, but for unknown reason it uses 8443 port, which will never be served (ends with timeout)

Configuration:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">   
    <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <!-- Other pages only autenticated  -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/userManagement.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/performanceMonitoring.xhtml" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/sessionExpired.xhtml">
    </security:session-management>

    <!-- Set the login page and what to do if login fails -->
    <security:form-login login-page="/login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/loginFail.xhtml" 
        default-target-url="/pages/statusOverview.xhtml" />
    <security:csrf/>
</security:http>
```

The other application instance, running on 7080 port does not have this problem, I guess there is some kind of hidden default behavior to change port exactly from 8080 -> 8443 in case of https request.

Is there a way to disable this behavior? I was looking for the answer but I didnt found any. The only solution I found was setting http and https ports explicitly in spring configuration which doesnt seem right to me. I want it configurable on tomcat config, not individually for each web application.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The issue is not of Spring Security but of Tomcat. In Tomcat you must have defined HTTPS port as 8443. So tomcat redirects https request to 8443

Comment: It cant be tomcat issue, because it works ok with any other pages, other than those intercepted by spring security. And even those have problem only before logging in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `secure="true"` on that connector along with `scheme="https"`.

Note that using port `8080` for secure-HTTP is like using port `80` for plaintext HTTP: [surprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

The value `8443` is coming from Tomcat's default `redirectPort` setting on the connector: Tomcat (or possibly Spring) is redirecting the user to what it thinks is the "secure" connector because all logins should be performed over TLS.

Comment: Didnt help :( Even tried to set the reditectPort in tomcat to something else, like 55555, but still spring redirects to 8443. Definitely the spring is the culprit.

Comment: I found solution setting following port mapping in Spring Security. `<security:port-mappings>
   <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8080"/>
  </security:port-mappings>` So I guess the default mapping is 8080 -> 8443, though I think it should be tomcats job to decide what port will be used for secure http, no springs.

Comment: @Gobanit It's up to whatever component performs the redirect. But if you are configuring a secure `<Connector>`, you should absolutely set it up to be labeled as secure.

Comment: I set it up, but the result was the same.

Comment: A workaround was given to this issue in the following link: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8140